# Save, Update and Delete is not working in Hibernate and Spring

Tags: spring, hibernate, service, dao, sessionfactory

This is my application-context, Dao Implementation class, and Service class. if I try to fetch any record, in response I have all the record in my objects but when I try to save or update or try to delete the object from database nothing happen without any exception.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

    <context:annotation-config />

    <context:component-scan base-package="org.prosigns.adminity.model.layers" />

    <mvc:annotation-driven />

    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />

    <context:property-placeholder location="classpath:hibernate.properties" />

    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource"
          p:driverClassName="${jdbc.driverClassName}" 
          p:url="${jdbc.url}"
          p:username="${jdbc.username}" 
          p:password="${jdbc.password}"/>

    <bean id="messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource" 
          p:basename="Messages" />

    <bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.prosigns.adminity.model.common.annotation.ScanningAnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="annotatedPackages">
            <list>
                <value>org.prosigns.adminity.model.layers.domain.**.*</value>
                <value>org.prosigns.adminity.model.layers.dao.**.*</value>
                <value>org.prosigns.adminity.model.layers.services.**.*</value>
            </list>
        </property>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${hibernate.dialect}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.connection.autocommit">false</prop>
                <prop key="org.hibernate.transaction">false</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">${hibernate.show_sql}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.format_sql">${hibernate.format_sql}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.use_sql_comments">${hibernate.use_sql_comments}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.max_fetch_depth">${hibernate.fetch_depth}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.current_session_context_class">${hibernate.current_session_context_class}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.transaction.factory_class">${hibernate.transaction_factory_class}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.bytecode.use_reflection_optimizer">${hibernate.use_reflection_optimizer}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.connection.release_mode">${hibernate.connection_release_mode}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.jdbc.batch_size">${hibernate.jdbc_batch_size}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache">${hibernate.cache_use_second_level_cache}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.cache.provider_class">net.sf.ehcache.hibernate.SingletonEhCacheProvider</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>



<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"/>
    </bean>    

</beans>

@Repository
public class PersistenceDaoImpl<T, PK extends Serializable> implements PersistenceDao<T, PK> {

    /** Class type. */
    Class<T> type;

    /**
     * Gets the current session in use (creates one if necessary).
     * @return Session object 
     */
    public Session getSession() throws DatabaseException{
        return SessionManager.getSessionFactory().openSession();
    }

    /**
     * Default bean constructor for spring.
     */
    public PersistenceDaoImpl() {
        // default constructor for spring
    }

    /**
     * Constructor.
     * @param type class type
     */
    public PersistenceDaoImpl(Class<T> type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    /** Helper functions.
     * @return the currently set class
     */
    public Class<T> getPersistentClass() {
        return this.type;
    }

    /**
     * Delete persistentObject from DB.
     * @param persistentObject object to delete.
     */
    public void delete(T persistentObject) throws DatabaseException{
        getSession().delete(persistentObject);

    }

    /** Deletes an object of a given Id. Will load the object internally so consider using delete (T obj) directly
     * @param id Delete key
     */
    public void delete(PK id) throws DatabaseException{
        getSession().delete(load(id));
    }

    /**
     * Loads the given Object.
     * @param id to load
     * @return T Loaded object
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public T load(PK id) throws DatabaseException{
        T t = (T) getSession().load(this.type, id);
        if (t == null){
            return (T) new Object();
        }
        return t;
    }


    /**
     * Loads the given Object.
     * @param id Id to load
     * @return An object of type T
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public T get(PK id) throws DatabaseException{
        return (T) getSession().get(this.type, id);
    }

    /**
     * Item to save.
     * @param o object to save
     * @return PK
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public PK save(T o) throws DatabaseException{
        return (PK) getSession().save(o);
    }

   /**
     * Item to refresh.
     * @param o object to refresh
     */
    public void refresh(T o) throws DatabaseException{
        getSession().refresh(o);
    }

    /**
     * Item to saveOrUpdate.
     * @param o item to save.
     */
    public void saveOrUpdate(T o) throws DatabaseException{
        getSession().saveOrUpdate(o);
    }

    /**
     * Update object.
     * @param o object to update
     */
    public void update(T o) throws DatabaseException{
        getSession().update(o);
    }

    /**
     * Get query.
     * @param s Query to execute.
     * @return Query object
     */
    public Query getQuery(String s) throws DatabaseException{
        return getSession().createQuery(s);
    }

    /** Delete object.
     * @param persistentObject to delete
     * @param session to use
     * 
     */
    public void delete(T persistentObject, Session session) throws DatabaseException{
        getSession().delete(persistentObject);
    }

    /** Deletes an object of a given Id. Will load the object internally so consider using delete (T obj) directly.
     * @param id to delete 
     * @param session to use
     */
    public void delete(PK id, Session session) throws DatabaseException{
        getSession().delete(load(id));
    }

    /**
     * Loads the given Object.
     * @param id to load
     * @param session to use
     * @return  an object of type T
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public T load(PK id, Session session) throws DatabaseException{
        return (T) session.load(this.type, id);
    }

    /**
     * Loads the given Object.
     * @param id Id to load
     * @param session Session to use
     * @return An object of type T
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public T get(PK id, Session session) throws DatabaseException{
        return (T) session.get(this.type, id);
    }

    /** Save object.
     * @param o to save 
     * @param session to use
     * @return the id of the saved object
     * 
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public PK save(T o, Session session) throws DatabaseException{
        return (PK) session.save(o);
    }

    /** Save Or Update object.
     * @param o to save
     * @param session to use.
     * 
     */
    public void saveOrUpdate(T o, Session session) throws DatabaseException{
        session.saveOrUpdate(o);
    }

    /** Update record.
     * @param o to update
     * @param session to use
     * 
     */
    public void update(T o, Session session) throws DatabaseException{
        session.update(o);
    }


    /**
     * GetQuery.
     * @param s to return
     * @param session  to use
     * @return Query object
     */
    public Query getQuery(String s, Session session) throws DatabaseException{
        return session.createQuery(s);
    }

    /** Wrapper around hibernate functions.
     * @param criterion to use
     * @return A list of matching objects
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public List<T> findByCriteria(Criterion... criterion) throws DatabaseException{
        Criteria criteria =  getSession().createCriteria(getPersistentClass());

        for (Criterion c : criterion) {
            criteria.add(c);
        }
        return criteria.list();
    }


    /** FindAll.
     * @return A list of all the objects
     */
    public List<T> findAll() throws DatabaseException{
        return findByCriteria();
    }

    /** Flushes the cache of the currently-used session.
     * @throws DatabaseException 
     * @throws HibernateException 
     * 
     */
    public void flush() throws DatabaseException {
        getSession().flush();
    }

    /** Object to evict from cache.
     * @param obj Object to evict
     */
    public void evict(Object obj) throws DatabaseException{
        getSession().evict(obj);
    }

    /** FindByExample.
     * @param exampleInstance to use
     * @param excludeProperty to use
     * @return List of matching objects
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public List<T> findByExample(T exampleInstance, String... excludeProperty) throws DatabaseException{
        Criteria criteria = getSession().createCriteria(getPersistentClass());
        Example example = Example.create(exampleInstance);
        for (String exclude : excludeProperty) {
            example.excludeProperty(exclude);
        }
        criteria.add(example);
        return criteria.list();
    }
}

@Service("crmAuthenticationService")
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.SUPPORTS, readOnly = true)
public class CrmAuthenticationServiceImpl implements CrmAuthenticationService{

    @Transactional (readOnly = false, propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED)
    public void saveUpdate(CrmAuthenticationVO vo) throws GenericException {
        if (vo.isForUpdate()){
            vo.setUpdatedBy(WebUtils.getLoggedUserId());
            vo.setUpdatedDate(CommonUtils.getCurrentDate());
        }else {
            vo.setAddedBy(WebUtils.getLoggedUserId());
            vo.setAddedDate(CommonUtils.getCurrentDate());
        }
        CrmAuthentication domain = new CrmAuthentication();
        domain.setValueObject(vo.getValueObject());
        DaoManager.getInstance().getCrmAuthenticationDao().update(domain);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to make the save, update and delete calls within a transaction.

Try adding the `@Transactional` annotation to your DAO. Spring will create a transaction-aware proxy to wrap your DAO. When the transaction finishes it will cause Hibernate to flush and commit.

Comment: should i use the annotation in implementation or in the interface?

Comment: Put it on your implementation class.

Comment: @Transactional (propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED)
    public void update(T o) throws DatabaseException{
     getSession().update(o);
    }


nothing happened after adding annotation in dao.

Comment: @NayabRaheel add it before your implementation class's name. For ex: Transactional public class UserDAOImpl{}